# Send email to particular segment and framework

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, email

I have two database tables, Email and Equipment.

```
Email(User will subscribe and select what segment and framework they want)
=====
ID , EMAIL, NAME , SEGMENT ,FRAMEWORK

Equipment(equipment name with all details)
=========
EQUIPMENT ID , COM_STATE , SEGMENT ,FRAMEWORK
```

There are many `segment` and `framework` values: how can I send email to particular `segment` and `framework`?

```
mail.To.Add(emailnam); #email to send  
mail.Body = (emailboyd); #email equipmentid with particular segment and framework
```

It is hard to explain. I try to join tables but it hard to merge one email with many equipment ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use if for email then gather all the information.it should be easy 
query from database then check

```
if(email=='')
{
  if (segment='')
 {  }
}
```